# How do you combine the takes from two comp recordings in Bitwig?

Tags: untagged

I have two separate comp recordings in Bitwig.  I would like to combine their takes so they can be a single large comping clip.  How do I do this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: idk Bitwig specifically, so I don't know precisely what commands you would use,  but on others you would either 'bounce in place' the overall comp track. [Personally, I wouldn't. I like to keep everything.] Or, alternatively, export the comp, then re- import; that way you have both, bounced comp + original takes.